# Mostrar control al entrar el ratón

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo un `TextBox` y quiero que mientras el ratón esté encima del control aparezca un `Button` en el lateral derecho, encima del `TextBox`. El caso es que el `TextBox` tiene también un comportamiento personalizado, por eso ambos controles se encuentran embebidos en un control personalizado que hereda de `UserControl`. Todo esto, por supuesto, usando `WinForms`.

Lo primero que se me ha ocurrido es controlar los eventos `MouseEnter`y `MouseLeave` tal y como se muestra a continuación:

```
public partial class MiControl : UserControl
{
  void textBox_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    boton.Visible = true;
  }

  void textBox_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    boton.Visible = false;
  }
}
```

Esta opción funciona bien hasta que el ratón se coloca encima del `Button`. En ese momento se empiezan a alternar ambos eventos de forma descontrolada y el único efecto visible es que el botón no puede ser pulsado. Lo cierto es que tiene todo el sentido del mundo: si el ratón se coloca encima del `Button` técnicamente está saliendo del `TextBox`, por lo que se lanza el evento `MouseLeave`. Esto último provoca que el ratón pase a estar dentro del `TextBox`, lo que lanza el evento `MouseEnter` y vuelta a empezar.

¿Cómo podría controlar esta situación?

Comment: ¿Windows forms o WPF? Por favor, añade la etiqueta apropiada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando se lanza el evento `MouseLeave`, comprueba si el ratón está todavía encima del `TextBox` usando la propiedad `ClientRectangle` del `TextBox` y la propiedad (estática) `Control.MousePosition` como sigue:

```cs
if(!textBox.ClientRectangle.Contains(textBox.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition)))
  boton.Visible = false;
```

Para asegurarse de que el botón se oculta cuando el ratón sale, también ejecutar esta actualización cuando se lanza el evento `MouseLeave` para el botón:

```cs
    void textBox_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ActualizarVisibilidad();
    }

    void boton_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ActualizarVisibilidad();
    }

    void ActualizarVisibilidad()
    {
        boton.Visible = textBox.ClientRectangle.Contains(textBox.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition));
    }
```